# Purchase extra baggage now or wait till checkin time?

Tags: luggage, qatar-airways

I am flying from Prague CZ to Sydney Australia using Qatar airways. I believe I will have extra baggage over the 30kg limit. I am unsure how much over I will be but probably 5-7kg and dont really have a way to calculate my baggage weight.

Should I purchase extra baggage now (they sell in 5-10 kg intervals) or wait till checkin desk, see if they flag me for being 5kg over and pay at checkin?

Comment: No airline I know overlooks 5kg. If it’s cheaper online, pay online. Otherwise wait till the airport.

Comment: If you have a bathroom scale, you can get a decent measurement by weighing yourself, weighing yourself holding your luggage, then subtracting. It works well with smaller bags, but could be difficult with a 30kg+ bag though.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend purchasing it online.

If you know you are going to be over it is cheaper to purchase it online. They probably will weigh it.

Price per additional KG:

Online - 55 USD
Offline - 70 USD